# How to do a Google Search with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, google-search

i have to use this Code to search in google and Show the result Link,but i dont know how to send My Query

```
    String s="reza";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/search?q=").userAgent("Mozilla").data(?????).get();
    Elements titles = doc.select(".entrytitle");

    //print all titles in main page
    for(Element e: titles){
        System.out.println("text: " +e.text());
        System.out.println("html: "+ e.html());
    }   

    //print all available links on page
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for(Element l: links){
        System.out.println("link: " +l.attr("abs:href"));
    }

}
```

"reza" is my query that i want to search it in google
How can i use this method to search
my problem is sending query to Google search page

Comment: Google doesn't allow automated requests, so question is about how to abuse Google's service.

Comment: But if you only do it a few times, for some extremely limited, short-term purpose, it should be fine.

Comment: If it's a single search based on user action then no it is not an automated request nor is it abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/search?q=")` to `Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/search?q=" + s)`.

And remove the `.data(???)`.